# slideToggle() multiple elements show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

When an element opens, all others open elements close .

I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#servico1').click(function() {
            jQuery('.descricao2').hide("slow");
            jQuery('.descricao3').hide("slow");
            jQuery('.descricao4').hide("slow");
            jQuery('.descricao1').slideToggle("slow");
    });
    jQuery('#servico2').click(function() {
            jQuery('.descricao1').hide("slow");
            jQuery('.descricao3').hide("slow");
            jQuery('.descricao4').hide("slow");
            jQuery('.descricao2').slideToggle("slow");

    });
    jQuery('#servico3').click(function() {
            jQuery('.descricao2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
    jQuery('#servico4').click(function() {
            jQuery('.descricao3').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

I know it's bad code and very repetitive.
I want to know how can I create a simpler and cleaner code.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ymL7o3bj/1/)

Comment: Sorry, i researched several examples, but i have not found your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

1) Use single click handler for all anchor element

2) Use clicked anchor index among anchor elements in same div to target the desired div.

3) slideToggle targeted div and hide its sibling divs.

```
$('a.d-box-effect7-menu').click(function(){
   $('.descricao'+($('.d-box-effect7-menu').index($(this))+1)).slideToggle("slow").siblings('div').hide('slow');
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: works fine for me :)

Comment: Works great. TY! Can you explain a bit your code?